# Searching from Cassandra database via SparkStreaming takes time

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using this line to get entries from my Cassandra database

```
val  data1 =
  ssc.
    cassandraTable("orbigo2", "my_trips").
    select("trip_id").
    where ("user_id=?", uid)
```

But this is taking a lot of time, I guess the reason is that my `uid` is not a primary key but an index key.

Is there any way in which I can speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

I would only recommend to change data model so the `uid` will become the partition key - in this case it will be much faster... Right now it's just scanning the whole table and extracting the necessary data.

Also, you may consider to use [DataFrames](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md) instead of RDD - it has more optimizations, and maybe you can use the secondary indexes. You can check the execution plan with `.explain` on the DataFrame to see how the data is accessed...